# Closedness of a complex $1$-form defined by homogeneous functions

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms

How can I prove this 1-form is a closed one within the specific subset $A\subset \mathbb C$ ?

$$\omega=\frac{f(x,y)}{xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)}dx+\frac{g(x,y)}{xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)}dy$$

Where $f, g\in C^1$ are homogeneous functions with the same degree $\lambda>0$, in sense that $f(tz)=t^{\lambda}f(z)$ and the same for $g$.
And $A=\{(x,y)|xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)\neq 0\}.$
 Sorry for my English. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, if

$$A(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)}$$
and
$$B(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)},$$

you can derive and find that

$$A_y=\frac{yf_yg-fg-yfg_y}{(xf+yg)^2}$$

and

$$B_x=\frac{xfg_x-fg-xf_xg}{(xf+yg)^2}.$$

**Theorem:** If $\omega=Adx+Bdy$ a 1-form is $C^1$ such that $A_y=B_x$, then $\omega$ is closed.

**Hint:** Use that $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous functions to conclude that.